# How to get the threshold value of swipeable jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want `threshold` value of `swipeable` item so I can do something when a certain threshold is reached. For example, changing the color of an item swiped empty place.

The swipeable can be added like :

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
        .swipeable(
            state = swipeAbleState,
            anchors = anchors,
            thresholds = { _, _ ->
                FractionalThreshold(.5f)
            },
            orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `swipeableState` to check current swipe progress and compare it with the threshold. I'm using [`derivedStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#derivedStateOf(kotlin.Function0)) to prevent redundant recompositions.

```
val threshold = 0.3f
val thresholdReached by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        swipeableState.progress.from != swipeableState.progress.to // check that we are not in the initial state
                && swipeableState.progress.fraction > threshold
    }
}
// ...
thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(threshold) },
```